# How to set the dynamic linker path for a shared library?

Tags: gcc, linker, shared-libraries, elf, ld

I want to compile a shared library with an `.interp` segment.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(int argc, char** argv) {

    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    return 0;

}
```

I'm using the following commands.

```
gcc -c -o test.o test.c
ld --dynamic-linker=blah -shared -o test.so test.o
```

I end up without an INTERP segment, as if I never passed the `--dynamic-linker=blah` option. Check with `readelf -l test.so`. When building an executable, the linker processes the option correctly and puts an INTERP segment in the program header. How to do I make it work for shared libraries too?

Answer (score 4):

`ld` doesn't include a .interp section if `-shared` is used, as @MichaelDillon already said. You can however provide this section yourself.

```
const char interp_section[] __attribute__((section(".interp"))) = "/path/to/dynamic/linker";
```

The line above will save the string "/path/to/dynamic/linker" in the .interp section using [GCC attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html).

If you're trying to build a shared object that's also executable by itself, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31484785/2073469) out. It has a more comprehensive description of the process.

Answer (score 2):

The INTERP segment only goes into binaries which need to load the ELF interpreter (ld.so) in the first place. A shared library has no INTERP segment because the ELF interpreter is already loaded before the shared library is loaded.

Comment: This is only true by default. You can make a shared object executable on its own by adding an INTERP section as @jacwah writes in his reply to the OP. For example, the glibc shared object is also an executable as you can see by doing `readelf -a /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | grep INTERP`.

Answer (score 0):

In most linux systems the ldconfig is run at every system boot and it looks definitions in /etc/ld.so.conf for looking in directories that have shared libraries. In the file /etc/ld.so.cache there are mappings for shared libraries sonames and the library full path. Consider reading this article: http://grahamwideman.wordpress.com/2009/02/09/the-linux-loader-and-how-it-finds-libraries/#comment-164