# How to make a linux shared object (library) runnable on its own?

Tags: c, linux

Noticing that `gcc -shared` creates an executable file, I just got the weird idea to check what happens when I try to run it ... well the result was a *segfault* for my own lib. So, being curious about that, I tried to "run" the glibc (`/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6` on my system). Sure enough, it didn't crash but provided me some output:

```
GNU C Library (Debian GLIBC 2.19-18) stable release version 2.19, by Roland McGrath et al.
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Compiled by GNU CC version 4.8.4.
Compiled on a Linux 3.16.7 system on 2015-04-14.
Available extensions:
    crypt add-on version 2.1 by Michael Glad and others
    GNU Libidn by Simon Josefsson
    Native POSIX Threads Library by Ulrich Drepper et al
    BIND-8.2.3-T5B
libc ABIs: UNIQUE IFUNC
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.debian.org/Bugs/>.
```

So my question here is: what is the magic behind this? I can't just define a `main` symbol in a library -- or can I?

Comment: libc is open source. To learn how its authors made it into both a dessert topping and a floor wax, you can look at the source.

Comment: @bmargulies I sometimes go to great lengths here to help ppl IFF I think the question is interesting ... sure I could dig through all the `glibc` source, looking for that text, etc ... still it would be a *lot* easier if someone knew the answer and could (ideally) point me to some *documentation*. AND it would maybe serve others just using google. So let's see ;)

Comment: Perhaps the real question here is "how can I make a shared library that has its own entrypoint?" [This question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40587/why-are-shared-libraries-executable) might be related.

Comment: @Octopus this is a useful link! Seems like some suggest that, indeed, `main` is defined in `glibc`. I'll just give it a try... [forget that, it's obviously NOT that easy]

Comment: Actually, I [found something](https://polentino911.wordpress.com/2013/08/08/make-your-own-executable-shared-library-on-linux/) myself now -- but there's still a question left: is this linux-specific? Well I'll try to implement it now...

Comment: This is exactly what you are looking for http://rachid.koucha.free.fr/tech_corner/executable_lib.html

Comment: @alvits yes, this is roughly the same I found myself (see earlier comment). Now I have two questions: 1) Is this linux-specific? (I guess so) and 2) how to find the actual program interpreter? Using `readelf` on `bin/ls` looks more like a workaround ...

Comment: The interpreter on linux is `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` and `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` provided by `glibc.x86_64` and `glibc.i686` respectively.

Comment: @alvits sure, I know this from my own system, but what about other platforms? I think thanks to the comments by everyone here, I'm close to an answer to my own question, but determining the correct program interpreter is still a problem .... (eg think about android on ARM)

Comment: On Solaris and Linux there is a utility called `readelf`. If you are writing an automake file, you can compile a stub file and use readelf to check which interpreter the compiler used. Such command will be `readelf -l stub` and you will see a line like `[Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]`. I am not aware of similar utility for any other platforms.

Comment: Ok, so this is probably the road I'll go down ... thanks ... background is I'm trying to create a "generic" framework of GNU make rules for compiling binaries and libraries (being fed up with `autotools`) ... :)

Comment: Cool. I'm glad you have it all figured out. On Solaris I found that `SUNWbinutils` has `greadelf`. Same as Linux's `readelf` just prepended with `g` for `GNU`.

Comment: ok, that means I'll have to introduce a platform specific READELF variable in my `gmake` rules. Thanks a lot for your input :)

Comment: `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` is an example of an executable shared library, btw

Answer (score 25, accepted):

*I wrote [a blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20170324131308/programmersdelight.com/2015/07/30/hello-libc/) on this subject where I go more in depth because I found it intriguing. You can find my original answer below.*

---

You can specify a custom entry point to the linker with the `-Wl,-e,entry_point` option to gcc, where `entry_point` is the name of the library's "main" function.

```
void entry_point()
{
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
}
```

The linker doesn't expect something linked with `-shared` to be run as an executable, and must be given some more information for the program to be runnable. If you try to run the library now, you will encounter a segmentation fault.

The .interp section is a part of the resulting binary that is needed by the OS to run the application. It's set automatically by the linker if `-shared` is not used. You must set this section manually in the C code if building a shared library that you want to execute by itself. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488937/how-to-set-the-dynamic-linker-path-for-a-shared-library).

The interpreter's job is to find and load the shared libraries needed by a program, prepare the program to run, and then run it. For the ELF format (ubiquitous for modern *nix) on Linux, the `ld-linux.so` program is used. See it's [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ld-linux) for more info.

The line below puts a string in the .interp section using [GCC attributes](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html). Put this in the global scope of your library to explicitly tell the linker that you want to include a dynamic linker path in your binary.

```
const char interp_section[] __attribute__((section(".interp"))) = "/path/to/ld-linux";
```

The easiest way to find the path to `ld-linux.so` is to run `ldd` on any normal application. Sample output from my system:

```
jacwah@jacob-mint17 ~ $ ldd $(which gcc)
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff259fe000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007faec5939000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007faec5d23000)
```

Once you've specified the interpreter your library should be executable! There's just one slight flaw: it will segfault when `entry_point` returns.

When you compile a program with `main`, it's not the first function to be called when executing it. `main` is actually called by another function called `_start`. This function is responsible for setting up `argv` and `argc` and other initialisation. It then calls `main`. When `main` returns, `_start` calls `exit` with the return value of `main`.

There's no return address on stack in `_start` as it's the first function to be called. If it tries to return, an invalid read occurs (ultimately causing a segmentation fault). This is exactly what is happening in our entry point function. Add a call to `exit` as the last line of your entry function to properly clean up and not crash.

**example.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const char interp_section[] __attribute__((section(".interp"))) = "/path/to/ld-linux";

void entry_point()
{
    printf("Hello, world!\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

Compile with `gcc example.c -shared -fPIC -Wl,-e,entry_point`.

Comment: Accepting this, because although MOST details were already in the comments, it is a really comprehensive answer and I guess the *segfault at exit* issue would have bitten me ;)

Comment: @FelixPalmen I thought that the question ought to have a proper answer as it's a really interesting one :)

Comment: might as well  write a regular main function and not have to specify a special entry_point

Comment: @PSkocik That would be missing the point. You can't link two objects that export the same symbol, e.g. `main`. To create a shared object that is both executable on it's own and dynamically linkable into a regular application is a bit more involved (see my answer).

Comment: Shared libraries don't usually export main, I think.

Comment: Let's continue this discussion in [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26109/room-for-jacwah-and-pskocik).

Comment: @jacwah playing around a bit with the stack, I came up with the following for *assembly-free* retrieval of command line arguments: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0f8dc99a1e164ff8 -- Of course dependent on the stack layout, so completely  platform-/implementation-specific. What baffles me is why leaving out the `void *res` in `struct stackframe` makes it break ...

Comment: @FelixPalmen Wow that's cool! I'm not sure why the void pointer is needed - maybe just an artefact of the function call interface (there is a return address there for normal functions). Can I link to it on my blog?

Comment: @FelixPalmen I did some research and came to realise that pushing `rbp` to the stack is part of the standard function calling sequence. GCC just adds it to the beginning of every function, even though it's not needed in this case. This is what the `void *` at the top of the stack is.

Comment: @jacwah -- ok, cool ;) Well, it's a dirty, very dirty hack ... and right now it crashes when the same code is compiled for `x86` ... I'm not sure whether you want to link *that* ;) I'll try to figure out with `gdb` what's wrong on `x86` (having put `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` as program interpreter of course...)

Answer (score 0):

While linking with `-shared` gcc strips start files, and some objects (like `cout`) will not be initialized. So, `std::cout << "Abc" << std::endl` will cause SEGFAULT.

## Approach 1

(simplest way to create executable library)

To fix it change linker options. The simplest way - run gcc to build executable with `-v` option (verbose) and see the linker command line. In this command line you should remove `-z now`,  `-pie` (if present) and add `-shared`. The sources must be anyway compiled with `-fPIC` (not `-fPIE`).

Let's try. For example we have the following **x.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>

// The next line is required, while building executable gcc will
// anyway include full path to ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:
extern "C" const char interp_section[] __attribute__((section(".interp"))) = "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2";

// some "library" function
extern "C"  __attribute__((visibility("default"))) int aaa() {
    std::cout << "AAA" << std::endl;
    return 1234;
}

// use main in a common way
int main() {
    std::cout << "Abc" << std::endl;
}
```

Firstly compile this file via `g++ -c x.cpp -fPIC`. Then will link it dumping command-line via `g++ x.o -o x -v`.

We will get correct executable, which can't be dynamically loaded as a shared library. Check this by python script **check_x.py**:

```py
import ctypes
d = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./x')
print(d.aaa())
```

Running `$ ./x` will be successful. Running `$ python check_x.py` will fail with `OSError: ./x: cannot dynamically load position-independent executable`.

While linking `g++` calls `collect2` linker wraper which calls `ld`. You can see command-line for `collect2` in the output of last `g++` command like this:

```sh
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/collect2 -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/liblto_plugin.so -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccqDN9Df.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc --build-id --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 --hash-style=gnu --as-needed -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -pie -z now -z relro -o x /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/crtbeginS.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../lib -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../.. x.o -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/crtendS.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
```

Find there `-pie -z now` and replace with `-shared`. After running this command you will get new `x` executable, which will wonderfully work as an executable and as a shared library:

```sh
$ ./x
Abc
$ python3 check_x.py
AAA
1234
```

This approach has disadvantages: it is hard to do replacement automatically. Also before calling `collect2` GCC will create a temporary file for LTO plugin (link-time optimization). This temporary file will be missing while you running the command manually.

## Approach 2

(applicable way to create executable library)

The idea is to change linker for GCC to own wrapper which will correct arguments for `collect2`. We will use the following Python script **collect3.py** as linker:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import subprocess, sys, os

marker = '--_wrapper_make_runnable_so'

def sublist_index(haystack, needle):
    for i in range(len(haystack) - len(needle)):
        if haystack[i:i+len(needle)] == needle: return i

def remove_sublist(haystack, needle):
    idx = sublist_index(haystack, needle)
    if idx is None: return haystack

    return haystack[:idx] + haystack[idx+len(needle):]

def fix_args(args):
    #print("!!BEFORE REPLACE ", *args)
    if marker not in args:
         return args

    args = remove_sublist(args, [marker])
    args = remove_sublist(args, ['-z', 'now'])
    args = remove_sublist(args, ['-pie'])

    args.append('-shared')
    #print("!!AFTER REPLACE ", *args)

    return args

# get search paths for linker directly from gcc
def findPaths(prefix = "programs: ="):
    for line in subprocess.run(['gcc', '-print-search-dirs'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode('utf-8').split('\n'):
        if line.startswith(prefix): return line[len(prefix):].split(':')

# get search paths for linker directly from gcc
def findLinker(linker_name = 'collect2'):
    for p in findPaths():
        candidate = os.path.join(p, linker_name)
        #print("!!CHECKING LINKER ", candidate)
        if os.path.exists(candidate) : return candidate

if __name__=='__main__':
    args = sys.argv[1:]
    args = fix_args(args)
    exit(subprocess.call([findLinker(), *args]))
```

This script will replace arguments and call true linker. To switch linker we will create the file **specs.txt** with the following content:

```
*linker:
<full path to>/collect3.py
```

To tell our fake linker that we want to correct arguments we will use the additional argument `--_wrapper_make_runnable_so`. So, the complete command line will be the following:

```sh
g++ -specs=specs.txt -Wl,--_wrapper_make_runnable_so x.o -o x
```

(we suppose that you want to link existing **x.o**).

After this you can both run the target `x` and use it as dynamic library.